# How to retrieve the unsaved output of a statement in python?

Tags: python

I ran this line to retrieve the paths of all the files in a directory and its subdirectories and forgot to save it in a variable and it takes hours to run it again because of the size of the dataset.

```
list(glob.glob(str(train_root)+'/**/info.txt',recursive=True))
```

Is it saved in a variable name reserved by python like `temp`?
then I can run `my_list=temp`.

Comment: if you are in an interactive console the return value of the last statement (unless it was assigned to a variable already) is assigned to `_` (single underscore). best to call something like `>>> mylist = _ ` quick before you overwrite `_`

Comment: IPython provides the full history: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.04-input-output-history.html  Just use `Out[NUMBER]`

Comment: Where did you ran this line? In a Python file, a Jupyter Notebook or the REPL?

Comment: everything goes away when you close the interpreter as well, so it's also probably best to save your file paths to a file using something like `with open("paths.txt", "w") as f; f.write("\n".join(mylist))`

Comment: I ran it in Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 0):

If you already ran the code, python released the memory after the code finished executing. You will likely have to rerun it to get the output.

If you ran this in IDLE, then you can certainly save to a file with something like:
`f = open('<output_file_name>','w')` and then `print(<string_of_data>, file=f)` or `f.write(<string_of_data>)`. Finish off with `f.close()`

Running that will save an output text file containing that variable. You may need to cast the array as a string and specify a path for the output file.